# Listas Simplemente Enlazadas - Eliminar elemento duplicado (int)

Tags: java

Estoy intentando eliminar de una **lista enlazada** los elementos duplicados independientemente de la posición en la que se encuentren en esta. Tengo una lista con **n** números enteros que se repiten de manera aleatoria en las posiciones de la lista, para ello he realizado un método que elimina los elementos duplicados, debería dejar tan solo los primeros números y los siguientes que se duplican eliminarlos...

Para ello he realizado varios bucles con **nodos** que recorren esta **lista**, uno que recorre de uno en uno y otro bucle en el interior de este que es el que recorre la **lista** entera por cada numero que tiene la lista y dentro de este una condición que prueba si son iguales el el nodo **p** con el nodo **q**
y un contador que cuenta cuantas veces se repite el numero, si este se repite mas de una vez, el nodo salta a la siguiente posición saltando este.

**Clase Nodo**

```
public class Nodo {

    private int info;
    private Nodo sig;

    public Nodo() {

        this.info = info;
        this.sig = sig;

    }

    public Nodo(int info) {

        this.info = info;
        this.sig = sig;

    }

    public int getInfo() {

        return info;

    }

    public void setInfo(int info) {

        this.info = info;

    }

    public Nodo getSig() {

        return sig;

    }

    public void setSig(Nodo sig) {

        this.sig = sig;

    }

}
```

**Clase Lista**

```
public class Lista {

    private Nodo com;

    public Lista() {

        this.com = null;

    }

    public Nodo getCom() {

        return com;

    }

    public void setCom(Nodo com) {

        this.com = com;

    }

    public boolean listaVacia() {

        return com == null;

    }

    public void insertarPrincipio(int info) {

        Nodo p = new Nodo();
        p.setInfo(info);
        p.setSig(com);
        com = p;

    }

    public int getSize() {

        Nodo p = com;
        int contador = 0;

        while(p!=null) {

            contador++;

            p = p.getSig();

        }

        return contador;

    }

    public void eliminarDuplicado() {

        Nodo p = com; //Nodo 1
        Nodo q = com;//Nodo 2
        int contador = 0; //Cuenta cuantas veces se repite el numero

        while(p!=null) { // 4,1,3,2,6,5,3,5,1,2,3,8,3,,7,5,6,3,2,4,5

            contador = 0;

                while(q!=null) { // 4,1,3,2,6,5,3,5,1,2,3,8,3,,7,5,6,3,2,4,5

                    if(p.getInfo()==q.getInfo()) {

                        contador++;

                    }

                    if(contador>1) {

                        q = q.getSig();

                    }

                    System.out.print(q.getInfo() + "-->");
                    q = q.getSig();

                }

            p = p.getSig();

        }

    }

    public String toString() {

        String s = "";

        Nodo p = com;

        if(listaVacia()==false) {

            while(p!=null) {

                s = s + p.getInfo() + "-->";

                p = p.getSig();

            }

        }else {

            s = "La lista esta vacia";

        }

        return s;

    }

}
```

**Clase Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Lista l1 = new Lista();

        llenar(l1);

        System.out.println(l1.toString());

        l1.eliminarDuplicado();



    }

    public static Lista llenar(Lista l1) {

        int numero [] = {5,4,2,3,6,5,7,3,8,3,2,1,5,3,5,6,2,3,1,4};

        for(int i=0; i<numero.length; i++) {

            l1.insertarPrincipio(numero[i]);

        }

        return l1;

    }

}
```

Salida esperada --> 4-1-3-2-6-5-8-7
Salida inesperada --> 4-1-3-2-6-5-3-5-1-2-3-8-3-7-5-3-2-5 (Elimina solo el primer elemento del primer bucle)

He mirado vídeos, documentación y no encuentro una posible solución si alguien me pudiera ayudar a entender por que mi salida recorre tan solo el primer elemento y no elimina todos los repetidos...

Answer (score 1):

No estás eliminando nodos, solo te los estás saltando. Por ser una lista enlazada simple para eliminar los nodos tienes que pararte en el nodo anterior al repetido y hacer esto `nodo.setSig(nodo.getSig().getSig())`. Así enlazas el nodo anterior con el nodo siguiente del que quieres eliminar. Te dejo el método `eliminarDuplicado` coregido:

```
public void eliminarDuplicado() {
    Nodo p = com;
    while(p!=null) {
        Nodo q = p;
        while(q.getSig() != null) {
            if(p.getInfo() == q.getSig().getInfo()) {
                q.setSig(q.getSig().getSig());
            } else {
                q = q.getSig();
            }
        }
        p = p.getSig();
    }
}
```

Ahora solo llama al método y vuelve a imprimir la lista después de llamarlo para que veas el resultado.